# display html form in react modal

Tags: reactjs, contact-form

I've built a react web app and within the app, there is a modal that will pop up with a contact form inside of it, the issue I have is that the contact form I have built is done with some HTML, CSS and some JavaScript how do I bring all of it into the modal, I'm pretty new to react and can't seem to find what I'm looking for online

here is my modal code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Box, Container, Flex } from "@chakra-ui/layout";
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Timeline from "../Events/Timeline";
import ProjectService from "../../services/project.service";
import ProjectDetailsCustomer from "../Project/ProjectDetailsCustomer";
import Form from '../contactForm/Form'
import { EmailIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import {
    Modal,
    ModalOverlay,
    ModalContent,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalFooter,
    ModalBody,
    ModalCloseButton,
  } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { useDisclosure } from "@chakra-ui/react"

const CustomerProjectView = (props) => {
    const projectId = props.match.params.param1;
    const [project, setProject] = useState(props.project);


    useEffect(() => {
        if (projectId !== undefined) {
            ProjectService.getProjectByID(projectId).then((projectReturned) => {
                setProject(projectReturned);
            });
        }
    }, [projectId]);

    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

    return (
        <Container maxW="6xl" marginTop={12} marginBottom={12}>
            <Flex bg={"brand.background"} borderRadius={8} boxShadow="lg">
                {projectId ? (
                    <Box m={10}>
                        <ProjectDetailsCustomer project={project} />
                        <>
                        <Button
                            leftIcon={<EmailIcon />}
                            colorScheme={"blue"}
                            marginBottom={20}
                            onClick={onOpen}>
                                Contact Us
                                </Button>

                        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                            <ModalOverlay />
                            <ModalContent>
                            <ModalHeader>Contact Form</ModalHeader>
                            <ModalCloseButton />
                            <ModalBody>
                                <Form />
                            </ModalBody>
                            <ModalFooter>
                                <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
                                Close
                                </Button>
                            </ModalFooter>
                            </ModalContent>
                        </Modal>
                        </>
            
                        <Timeline project={project} />
                    </Box>
                ) : (
                    <></>
                )}
            </Flex>
        </Container>
    );

};

export default CustomerProjectView;
```

**************CODE BELOW IS THE HTML ******************

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/contact.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact us</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <form class="contact-form">
            <h2>CONTACT FORM</h2>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full name"></br>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"></br>
                <input type="test" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"></br>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></br>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message"></br>
            </form>
        </div> 
        <script src="/js/contact.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this html file your `Form` component?

Comment: You need to provide more info, are you using webpack to build this project? any framework like Next.js? or just using a simple script tag?

Comment: yes the html file is my form component and I believe webpack is being used and just script tags for the html